# Persistent List Python Implementation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, queue

I have class that sends logs to an exposed API. Now what I want to happen is to save/persists failed logs in a list so that it can be resent to the server again.

This is what I have so far. 
You may notice that I have declared a class variable, and I have [read](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) that this is not really advisable.

My concern is, is there a better way to persist lists or queues?

```
from collections import *
import time
import threading
import requests
import json


URL_POST = "http:/some/url/here"

class LogManager:
    listQueue = deque()

    def post(self, log):
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",
               "Accept": "text/plain", "User-Agent": "Test user agent"}
        resp = requests.post(URL_POST, data=json.dumps(log), headers=headers)
        return resp.status_code

    def send_log(self, log):
        try:
            print ("Sending log to backend")
            self.post(log)
        except: # sending to server fails for some reason
            print ("Sending logs to server fail, appending to Queue")
            LogManager.listQueue.append(log)

    def resend_log(self, log):
        print ("checking if deque has values")

        if LogManager.listQueue:
            logToPost = LogManager.listQueue.popleft()
            try:
                self.post(logToPost)
                print ("resending failed logs")
            except: #for some reason it fails again
                LogManager.listQueue.appendleft(logToPost)
                print ("appending log back to deque")

    def run(self,log):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_log, args=(log,))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.resend_log,args=(log,))
        t1.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        logs =  LogManager()
        logs.run({"some log": "test logs"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only variable LogManager stores is a persistent one, there doesn't seem to be any need to re-instantiate the class each time. I would probably move the `logs = LogManager()` line outside of the while-loop and change `list_queue` to an instance variable, `self.list_queue` that is created in the class' `__init__` method. This way you'll have one LogManager with one queue that just calls its `run` method each loop.

That said, if you're keeping it inside the loop because your class will have further functionality that requires a new instance each loop, then using a class variable to track a list between instances is exactly what class variables are for. They're not inadvisable at all; the example given in the documentation you link to is bad because they're using a class variable for data that should be instance-specific.